# Limiting -Wsuggest-attribute to certain files

Tags: gcc

GCC's C and C++ compilers have several useful warning options, such as

- `-Wsuggest-attribute=pure`
- `-Wsuggest-attribute=const`
- `-Wsuggest-attribute=format`

and so on. When I try to compile my code with these options, the compiler also issues warnings on the code in the (header-only) libraries that I use. Is there a way to apply the warnings only on my code, e.g. by listing the directories that include relevant files or by some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into GCC's [Diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) -- these are supported in the following form since gcc-4.5.

After the `#include` of all library-headers you do not care about, add:
    #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wsuggest-attribute=format"
and further warnings to be enabled, to be warned of attributes to be added.

E.g. the following `my_printf` could use the `attribute(format)` specifier:

```
int my_printf(const char * format, ...) __attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 1, 2)));
int my_printf(const char * format, ...) {
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    vprintf (format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return 0;
}
```